# is it possible to get the current page number when using react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-pdf

I am using the react-pdf to show the pdf files, the code look like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import styles from './Previewer.module.css';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';
import { PDFDocumentProxy } from 'pdfjs-dist';
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;
import 'react-pdf/dist/Page/TextLayer.css';
import 'react-pdf/dist/Page/AnnotationLayer.css';

export type ViewerProps = {
    pdfUrl: string | undefined;
};

const Previewer: React.FC<ViewerProps> = (props: ViewerProps) => {

    const [pdfScale, setPdfScale] = useState<number>(1);
    const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState<number>();
    const [currentPage, setCurrentPage] = useState(1);
    const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState<number>(1);

    const options = {
        cMapUrl: 'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/pdfjs-dist@3.9.179/cmaps/',
    };

    if (!props.pdfUrl) {
        return (<div>Loading</div>);
    }

    const handleDownloadPdf = async (pdfUrl: any) => {
        if (!pdfUrl) {
            toast.error("PDF Url is null");
            return;
        }
        try {
            const response = await fetch(pdfUrl);
            const blob = await response.blob();
            const downloadUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([blob]));
            const link = document.createElement('a');
            link.href = downloadUrl;
            link.setAttribute('download', 'main.pdf');
            document.body.appendChild(link);
            link.click();
            document.body.removeChild(link);
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error downloading PDF:', error);
        }
    }

    const handleZoomIn = async () => {
        setPdfScale(pdfScale + 0.1);
    }

    const handleZoomOut = async () => {
        setPdfScale(pdfScale - 0.1);
    }

    const onDocumentLoadSuccess = (pdf: any) => {
        const { doc, numPages } = pdf;
        setNumPages(numPages);
    }

    const handlePageChange = (page: any) => {
        //setCurrentPage(page);
    };

    const handlePageRenderSuccess = (page: any) => {
        const pageIndex = page._pageIndex + 1;
    };

    const renderPages = (totalPageNum: number | undefined) => {
        if (!totalPageNum || totalPageNum < 1) return;
        const tagList: JSX.Element[] = [];
        for (let i = 1; i <= totalPageNum; i++) {
            tagList.push(
                <Page key={i}
                    className={styles.pdfPage}
                    scale={pdfScale}
                    onLoad={handlePageChange}
                    onRenderSuccess={handlePageRenderSuccess}
                    pageNumber={i} >
                        
                </Page>
            );
        }
        return tagList;
    }

    return (
        <div id="preview" className={styles.preview}>
            <div className={styles.previewHader}>
                <button onClick={() => { handleDownloadPdf(props.pdfUrl) }}>下载PDF</button>
                <button id="zoominbutton" onClick={() => { handleZoomIn() }}>放大</button>
                <button id="zoomoutbutton" onClick={() => { handleZoomOut() }}>缩小</button>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.previewBody}>
                <Document options={options} file={props.pdfUrl} onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
                    {renderPages(numPages)}
                </Document>
            </div>
            <div className={styles.previewFooter}>
                <p>
                    Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default Previewer;
```

I rendered the whole pdf and scroll to preview each page of the pdf file. In the footer of the page, I want to show the {currentScrolledPage}/{totalPage}. now the problem is that I did not know how to get the current sroll page of the pdf. I followed the official demo seems it does not work as expect. is it possible to get the current scrolled page? I have tried to change the page in fucntion `handlePageChange` and `handlePageRenderSuccess`, both did not work.

Comment: react-pdf library doesn't provide a direct way to get current scrolled page in same way as current pageNumber prop for rendering pages

Comment: is there any clue to get the current page? need I caculate the scroll position and get the total height to know the scroll page?

Comment: you can calculate the scroll position and compare it to the height of each page. You can use the PDFs rendered dimensions to estimate the page height